# WordPress/Versionpress: Problems with menus and ID's

Tags: wordpress, git

I'm using Versionpress to build a staging site for one of my projects. Everything works fine, except some problems with the menus and some content elements.

First of all, the menu isn't correct anymore. It is empty and shows no correct pages in it.

One other problem is the behaviour of some links based on page ID's (get_page_link()). Versionpress changes all ID's and therefore the theme uses the wrong ID to get a link or an image.

Is there any way to use/keep the right ID's?

Comment: I saw one work around in the wp-config that checked server url and picked db connection based on this, you could then deploy the same code to either site and have a duplicate backend. everything ID wise would remain the same. There are tools for syncing DBs. HTH.

Comment: do you have a link to the workaround?

Comment: here is some info on the topic https://codex.wordpress.org/Running_a_Development_Copy_of_WordPress#Creating_a_Second_Installation_With_Separate_Tables and this page explains what I had in mind https://mardell.me/blog/how-to-use-a-single-wordpress-config-for-local-and-remote-environments/

Comment: thanks for the link but I don't see how this would help me in combination with versionpress

Comment: I think this would work instead of, rather than with. sorry i didn't make that clear.

Comment: ok, thanks. I will keep it in mind ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Menus should work fine. Do you use plugins on this site? An incompatibility here might be causing this.
2. Hardcoded IDs in templates, CSS and similar places are an inherent problem with no easy solution. It's described in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/versionpress/versionpress/issues/1189).

By the way, there a [support repo](https://github.com/versionpress/support) that the team observes; feel free to post more details there.

Comment: Hmm, I don't use plugins for the menu. And I don't use hard coded IDs in the template. I'm using ACF to get an ID from a page and use this ID to get an image or a title, link or whatever. I will look at your support repo, thanks!